# paper_trail 7.1.3 Support for ActiveRecord < 4.2

Tags: paper-trail-gem

We are using rails 4.1.15 & ActiveRecord 4.1.15. We integrated with the latest version of paper_trail(7.1.3) that supports our rails version.

When using this, we receive a warning:

`DEPRECATION WARNING: Your version of ActiveRecord (< 4.2) has reached EOL. PaperTrail will soon drop support. Please upgrade ActiveRecord ASAP.`
(This change was added in March 2017 as part of [commit](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/commit/dc4fc621ef3da5beacca39b0d5f42be18180f39e))

As we have a huge application and no current plans to upgrade our rails, wanted to understand a few things:

1. `PaperTrail will soon drop support` - When will this happen?
2. When PaperTrail does drop support, what will be the impact? I assume that it will work just fine. Is there something we need to be careful of?
3. Is there is a way to suppress this warning?

Answer (score 0):

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Your version of ActiveRecord (< 4.2) has reached EOL. PaperTrail will soon drop support. Please upgrade ActiveRecord ASAP. (This change was added in March 2017 as part of commit)
>
> 1. PaperTrail will soon drop support - When will this happen?

This happened years ago. See the changelog for exact date.

> 2. When PaperTrail does drop support, what will be the impact? I assume that it will work just fine. Is there something we need to be careful of?

You can continue to use old, unsupported versions of PT and/or rails as long as you want.

> 3. Is there is a way to suppress this warning?

You could fork PT, or pipe to `/dev/null`.